# Paypal loses session data

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-paypal, paypal, django-oscar

Am using django oscar paypal and django oscar-0.7, when i submit for payment page get redirected to paypal site. After continuing that step and redirecting back to my site, it shows basket is empty and all paypal session is lost. Am stuck up here. Please help me in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was i was using get method for redirecting to paypal,later i changed that to post and it worked for me.I have used oscar for this, in that checkout view i wrote redirection in post function,which made it work